# Github best practices - How to maintain multiple user interfaces

Tags: android, user-interface, github

I am a android developer, and I'm developing an application that have multiple user interfaces.

Question: What is the best practice for maintaining multiple interfaces on github ?

Thanks for help :D

Comment: In what does the GUI differentiate?

Comment: @stefanbachert The core is the same, however, probably will change the positions of icons and layout according to each client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do rather use the functionality of the android environment

You could setup a (base) library android project and N depending (gui) project.
The depending projects may have own code and resources.

Each project will probably use an own trunk in git

Answer (score 3):

Just create different branches for different interfaces.